# Beginner html/css site layout

Tags: html, css

Now, I'm a real beginner, just starting, figuring out things, testing and trying html and css. I want to make something more or less like this (see picture). I want it to fully scale to fit the browser/resolution preserving aspect ratio.

[my layout](http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/3791/layoutr.jpg)

My html and css code is below. The background image scales fine but now I want my navigation to scale the same way. How to do it? What to change? I also want to have a dotted line under the solid one (above the navigation). Any advice? :) Just starting/learning/making mistakes :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Layout</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> HOME </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> O MNIE </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> OFERTA </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> STREFA ŚLUBNA </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> PUBLIKACJE </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> WSPOŁPRACA </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> BACKSTAGE </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> KONTAKT </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And css:

```
html 
{ 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: thin;
}
#navigation ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 18px;
}
#navigation li a
{
    color: #FFF; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#navigation li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #F69;
}
#navigation li a:active
{
    color: #F69;
}
```

Comment: You you expect the fonts size to scale?

Comment: you can make another border in the navigation and make the border-style: dotted

Comment: Your question is vague, please make it more clear what the actual practical problem is.

Comment: Sorry if my question is a little bit vague but as I said I'm just starting and I'm not sure how to clearly say what I mean, but I will try with all the answers I got already and if those won't help, then I will try to make myself more clear :) thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set any widths, heights, margins and paddings of the navigation elements to a percentage value. Maybe also set a percentage value to `font-size`. Just play around with numbers to see how thats affects your layout. In short, don't use fixed pixel values for the layout. You may use them to style individual buttons or similar elements in the layout.

BTW: Browser Support for `background-size` values `contain` and `cover`:

- Chrome 3.0
- Firefox (Gecko) 3.6 (1.9.2)
- Internet Explorer 9.0
- Opera 10.0
- Safari (WebKit) 4.1 (532)

(as stated at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

To your dotted border: you could use a horizontally repeated background image for such a layout or you set a solid border to a wrapper-element and a dotted border to the inner navigation-element.

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful for me :) I will try to change the values to %.

Answer (score 0):

do you try on

```
#navigation
{
width: auto;
}
```

?

Comment: yes I tried it, with "auto" the navigation bar is only under the menu buttons, so it ends where the navigation buttons. (covers only half ot the page width)

Answer (score 0):

Your margin attributes to the nav items need to be % or em. Right now you have them set explicitly to pixels. This is preventing them from "scaling"

if you are using static html or deriving them from a database all you need to do is the following :

(100 / #ofNavs) /2 = left || right margin value.

If you use borders or such, you'll need to add that into your figure math.